# Create Ad error - No Permission to access targeting relax option

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I use facebook marketing API to create AdSet (v 2.8, with java sdk). It is ok to get campaign and adset information. However, when I call to create AdSet, facebook returns this strange error. The access token is already generated with "ad_managements" and the ad account is already added to AdAPI list. There is no idea on about "targeting_relax_option" and the errror subcode "1815264".

> com.facebook.ads.sdk.APIException$FailedRequestException: {"error":{"message":"Application does not have permission for this action","type":"OAuthException","code":10,"error_subcode":1815264,"is_transient":false,"error_user_title":"No Permission to access targeting relax option","error_user_msg":"Field 'targeting_relax_option' is not available to your app, please contact Facebook for whitelist.","fbtrace_id":"EStH8rja1NP"}}

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I excluded the field "targeting_optimization", it's fine now. (v2.8)